# Infrared light absorption characteristics of vegetable oil

Tags: infrared-radiation

How much infrared light is absorbed by vegetable oil?

Comment: You need to ask whether the plastic container absorbs the IR

Comment: You also need to specify the IR spectrum which is to used to illuminate/heat the oil.

Comment: There's a world of details and possibilities hidden behind your word "feasible". Perhaps more description of just what you're thinking of would help.

Comment: Great question. Too bad I now need to go find the answer somewhere else.